# How to combine the value of two columns in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

inside my CASE statement I will select the values of two columns (b.start_time and c.end_time). I tried it this way but it doesn´t work.

for example:

```
SELECT
     CASE WHEN a.id = 4 THEN (SELECT (b.start_time , c.end_time) 
                              FROM table b, table c WHERE ...)
     END as time    
INTO table test


FROM ...

WHERE ... `
```

start_time: 1000
end_time: 1100

**Result:**

```
time: 10.00,11.00
```

I can select one value either start or end time. But how can I select both value and put it into one column?
Is this possible?

Comment: That's a case expression, not statement.

Comment: The syntax will depend on your DBMS. Please tag it. Also, old-style joins are **never** a good idea

Comment: So many syntax issues... Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Show us the whole query. Perhaps you should skip the case and instead move the condition to the WHERE clause.

Comment: I use PostgreSQL.... it is working with the concat statement from Ryan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

Just use `SELECT CONCAT(b.start_time, c.end_time) FROM ...`

Heres a link to the MySQl documentation: [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

Comment: Where do you know from that OP is using mysql engine?

Comment: Concat timestamps?

Comment: I just assumed, but the sytnax is very similar for other SQL's